# Batch File to append todays date

Tags: windows-7

I Run a batch file which saves as a filename.txt format but I need to know how to provide command which saves as filename_dd/mm/yy.txt format.

For Example I need it to save as Superuser_10-Oct-2016.txt format.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%date%` that would give you something like 2016-10-12 *(year-month-day)*. Now you just need to asign that to different variables by doing:

```
set day=%date:~8,2%
set month=%date:~5,2%
set year=%date:~0,4%
```

then you just need to get that into the filename. And as you **can't use** **"/"** in a command i use **"-"**:

```
echo "text goes here" >> filename_%day%-%month%-%year%.txt
```

**And Voila!**

And if you want to use the names for the months and not the numbers:

```
if %monthc%==1 set month=Jan

if %monthc%==2 set month=Feb

if %monthc%==3 set month=Mar

if %monthc%==4 set month=Apr

if %monthc%==5 set month=May

if %monthc%==6 set month=Jun

if %monthc%==7 set month=Jul

if %monthc%==8 set month=Aug

if %monthc%==9 set month=Sep

if %monthc%==10 set month=Oct

if %monthc%==11 set month=Nov

if %monthc%==12 set month=Dec
```

**Just be sure to add a c to the end of the first set command** (the one with: "set month=%date:~5,2%)

[**Variable Substring**](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)